# Compare multimap with String

Tags: c++, multimap

I want to compare an element from a multimap with a string, like:

```
struct value { 
string res;
time_t t;
};

string result; 

multimap<int, value> values
value new_value;  

if((values.find(new_value.res)) != result)    // code snipped
{
//... do something
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What was wrong with your code? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::find` and a lambda expression

```
auto it=std::find_if(values.begin(), values.end(), [&](const std::pair<int,value> &pair)
{
  return pair.second.res == new_value.res
});

if (it != values.end())
{
  // Found it
}
```

If you don't have access to C++11 then you can loop over it:

```
for(std::map<int,value>::iterator it=values.begin(); it!=values.end(); ++it)
{
  if( (*it).second.res == new_value.res)
  {
    // Found it,
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `std::find_if`? The `std::find` function takes the *value* to find as the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the [`std::multimap::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/find) function for this, as it only searches for keys.

Instead you have to use the more generic [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) function, with a custom predicate. Something like

```
std::find_if(std::begin(values), std::end(values),
    [&new_value](const std::pair<const int, value> &p)
    {
        return p.second == new_value.res;
    });
```

Comment: I think you mean `const std::pair<const int, value &p` as the `int` is mapped to a `value` structure, not a `std::string`

Comment: @Sean You're right. Don't know how I could have misread that. :)